# Is there a console scroll lock in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've recently moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ and one feature I'm missing (or maybe just can't find) is the console scroll lock i.e. stop refocusing on the latest console entry.

Is this possible in IntelliJ? I'm using v9 Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It depends where your cursor is. Just click on the part you want to be scroll locked.

Comment: How do I unlock the scroll? Even if I click off the console, it remains locked.

Comment: @rmcc: put your cursor to the bottom of the console

Comment: @aholub7x I don't think that's true, or at least, isn't true in IntellijJ 13.1.3. To get it to continue scrolling, I had to click the "Scroll to the end" icon on the right hand side. The icon is underneath the trashcan icon.

Comment: @StealthRabbi that exactly what the button does :)

Comment: @aholub7x You said "put your cursor at the bottom of the console". You didn't say to click an icon. Putting your cursor at the bottom does nothing, hence my previous response.

Answer (score 13):

To unlock the scrollbar, click on the last line (should be blank) of the console.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to this for google reasons - clicking at the bottom is hard when the console is still scrolling, it's a bit of a race - but control-end (or cmd-end on mac) also did it!

Comment: Thanks! the shortcut for this is: cmd + fn + right arrow

Answer (score 3):

To unlock the scrolling just press "Enter" key inside of console window.

Answer (score 1):

To Unlock the scroll lock on intelliJ 14 (probably earlier as well) on OSX its

fn + cmd + right cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2017, there is a "Scroll to the end" button in the "Console" tab of the Debug window.

Disabling it stops the auto scroll on output.