# How to lock scrolling in IntelliJ console?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, ide

Is there a way to scroll lock the console in IntelliJ 2017+?

I tried the instructions in the following question, but looks like this doesn't work anymore for recent IntelliJ versions.
[Is there a console scroll lock in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3529137/1353394)

Comment: if it does not work anymore, then it is a bug. It works fine for me on 2017.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Meo mentioned, it is currently a open bug in IntelliJ.
Here is the link to the the issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140061